# Convert UNIX Timestamp

Tags: time

I have an UNIX Timestamp in my Arduino Sketch and would like to get the day of the week of this timestamp (1-7).

How can I convert the timestamp to get the day of the week?

Comment: Do you mean, your program will be given a UNIX Timestamp number as data and should produce a day-of-the-week number?  Or that you have a timestamp number and want to know its day-of-the-week number?  If the latter, the Unix date command can tell you, via format code +%u.  Eg, if `date +%s` says 1455407637 (for Sat Feb 13 16:53:57 MST 2016), `date -d@1455407637 +%u` says 6.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to that problem is to download the [Time](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time) library and use the [weekday()](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/blob/master/TimeLib.h#L114) function:

```
int weekday(time_t t); // the weekday for the given time
```

Cheers!

Comment: One caveat, the `breakTime()` code at line 168 of [Time.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/master/Time.cpp) computes `Wday = (t/(60*60*24) + 4) % 7) + 1`, ie, it apparently ignores [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) [26 in number since 1972] so for 26 seconds before every midnight the day-of-the-week calc will be off by 1.

Comment: Ignore previous comment.  As noted in wikipedia's [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) article, Unix timestamps don't count leap seconds, so they are locally correct and calculations near midnight will be ok, except during a leap second itself.  Also see Eric Raymond's [Time, Clock, and Calendar Programming In C](http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming) article, and the article [Unix leap seconds](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/unix-leap-seconds.html).

Comment: UNIX timestamps are also kept in GMT/UTC time.  So you may run into problems with it being some hours out.  If so look to the functions gmtime() Vs locatime().  You may need to set your time-zone.  Oh and watch out for daylight savings time if it matters for your project.